# Not able to add repository in Xcode 8.2.1 from TFS

Tags: ios, xcode, git, ssh, tfs

In my repository there are two spaces . So I am entering %20 instead of space while adding repository. But when I try to add repository with SSH, %20 automatically replace with space . So I get "Repository Not Found" error.
Help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check if you are using the correct url for SSH format, you could find the info in

**TFS web portal - Your Repo - Clone** (*top right corner*)

[image]

Need to use `ssh://` and port 22 not 8080, the complete URL for a repository with space should be something as below:

```
ssh://yourtfsserver:22/GITAgile/_git/test%20space%20repo
```

---

**Update**

After enter the url with %20, it will  automatically replace %20 with space in the **Enter repository information** page.

[image]

Even though directly using with the space in http url, you still will get the correct repo from server.
[image]

Comment: Yes I have copied url for SSH format .
Now I have removed the spaces from URL still am getting same error "the repository location not found".
Is it with MAC ?
Because I also have tried with eclipse SVN but same error am getting..

Comment: @SanketPund  Yes it will  automatically replace `%20` with space. However it doesn't matter. Use both %20 or space directly could work with **http**.  To connect to your Git repos through SSH , you need to [use SSH key authentication](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate)  instead of username and password. Or use http as a workaround.

Comment: I also have created SSH key and used that but I only get "The repository location not found".
I have tried this in Xcode and Eclipse also but when I use this through Terminal, it reachable and I able to Pull and Push.
Is there any problem with TFS with these application ?

Comment: @SanketPund Could you give a try with manually changing the url  from back space to %20 again in the address bar- in the Enter repository information page.  And did this work with http format? What's your TFS version? Using SSH is only support after TFS 2015 update3.

Comment: I have changed the URL and now it doesn't contain any space still same error. With https, am getting "credential were rejected" error. So am trying with SSH only.
And am using latest version of TFS.

Comment: @SanketPund When using the http url to add a repo in your XCode , make sure there is **no proxy**. Also try to **enable basic authentication** in IIS on your TFS server. https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/configureBasicAuth.md Which worked for me.